# Reload page after click OK on the Alert Page

Tags: javascript, alert, reload, page-refresh

I want to reload page after clicking OK button on the javascript Alert box.
Here is my code :

```
$(".erase").click(function () {
    var answer = confirm("Delete This Data?");
    if (answer === true) {
        var erase = false;
        if (!erase) { 
            erase = true; 
            $.post('delete.php', {id: $(this).attr('data-id')} );
            erase = false;  
        }
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

if I put the window.location.reload(); there, the page reloading after click OK, but I can't delete the data I want.
If I remove it, I can delete the data but the page doesn't reload.

Please help me on this

Comment: yes ofcourse, I'm sorry

Answer (score 2):

You just need to provide the `window.reload()` as a callback to `$.post`.

```
$(".erase").click(function () {
    var answer = confirm("Delete This Data?");
    if (answer === true) {
        var erase = false;
        if (!erase) { 
            erase = true; 
            $.post('delete.php', {id: $(this).attr('data-id')}, function() { // here's the new bit
               window.location.reload();
            } );
            erase = false;  
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your first line to (I write code from head):

```
$(".erase").click(async function () {
```

and line with `$.post` to this:

```
let postResult = await Promise.resolve($.post('delete.php', {id: $(this).attr('data-id')} ));
```

Comment: Note that `await` may have limited IE support without a polyfill. https://caniuse.com/#search=await